# MySQL -- SELECT Command denied to user

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-workbench

This is a syntax error i am positive ...  However I am banging my head as to 'why'.  I have searched all "like" questions here on SO and they all (mostly) address a user with wrong permissions .. I assure you this isn't the case.

This  is my Query:

```
use database;    # I am using workbench .. I use this so I don't have to database.table  

SELECT firstname
FROM user, user_role
LEFT JOIN user.uid ON user_role.uid

WHERE user.firstname LIKE '%zak%';
```

The exact error is

```
Error Code: 1142. SELECT command denied to user '###'@'##.##.##.##' for table 'uid' 0.197 sec
```

I am not looking for a TABLE called `uid` ..  I am looking for the FIELD `iud`.

I have truncated the statement down to this portion that's causing the error .. There are other fields and other tables .. But I simply can't `JOIN`.

Is is a logical error with the location of the `.` for field identification?

Comment: The join pattern is `FROM table1 JOIN table2 ON <matching column condition>`. You are using something like `FROM table1, table2 JOIN table1.column ON table2.column`. That's an incorrect mix of implicit and explicit joins.

Comment: I dont think so if query is wrong and u get command denied error. Also chk user privileges

Comment: @ devpro .. You couldn't resist ...  Did you read my entire post?  The denied error is because the `table` it's looking for doesn't exist.  @Lloyd Banks is correct ... I was using comma separated tables AND `JOIN`  ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using:

```
SELECT firstname
FROM user, user_role
WHERE user.uid = user_role.uid
```

If you want all records in the `user` table regardless of what's in `user_role`, use

```
SELECT firstname
FROM user
    LEFT JOIN user_role
ON user.uid = user_role.uid
```

Using commas to separate tables and using the `JOIN` keyword is mutually exclusive.  It's either one or the other.  Using commas to separate tables is the same as an inner join.  If you want an outer join (with keywords `LEFT` or `RIGHT`), then you'll have to use the format with the `JOIN` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

Try writing it this way:

```
SELECT firstname
FROM user 
LEFT JOIN user_role ON user.uid = user_role.uid
WHERE firstname LIKE '%zak%';
```